# Does NativeAdsManager auto refresh native ads after impression of all loaded native ads?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

Does NativeAdsManager auto refresh native ads after impression of all loaded native ads? suppose i am initializing NativeAdsManager for 5 ads.

NativeAdsManager manager = new NativeAdsManager(this, "PLACEMENT_ID", 5) ;
will manager auto reload  after calling  manager.nextNativeAd()  5 time?